# How to find out full URL for Angular application including named outlets?

Tags: angular, url, router

I've been checking both [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) and [RouterOutlet](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) to see if I can find out what the entire URL line is. I can't see anything applicable, though.

Optimally, I'd like it to be presented in a split-up form, meaning that if the URL in my browser says:

> http://localhost:2006/some(aa:aha,bb:bha)

I'd get an object that would have fields like this:

> ...xxx.url.path = some
>   ...xxx.url.outlets[0] = {name:"aa", path: "aha"}
>   ...xxx.url.outlets[1] = {name:"bb", path: "bha"}
>   ...xxx.url.server = "localhost"
>   ...xxx.url.port = 2006

although, even a compounded version like the below would do, since I'll be able to split it up myself with some string magic.

> ...xxx.url.path = some(aa:aha,bb:bha)

How do I do that? What keys have I missed when googling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the current url via the Router class or the Location class.

```js
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
constructor(private router: Router) { }

console.log(this.router.url);
```

or

```js
import { Location } from "@angular/common";
constructor(private location: Location) { }

console.log(this.location.path());
```

Note that the router redirects the user, so depending on your configuration you could have to subscribe to the NavigationEnd event to make sure the user was redirected.

```js
import { Event, NavigationEnd } from "@angular/router";

this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => { 
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd){ 
    // do your stuff here 
  } 
});
```